# Dropped spines in pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

How can I achieve something similar to the "dropped spines" example below using **pgfplots**?

[image: from matplotlib.sourceforge.com]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think pgfplots has an option for this out of the box, but you can relatively easily achieve this using the various styles that control axis lines, tick marks and tick labels:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[clip=false, % don't clip the graph at the "virtual edge" of the plot
ymin=-1, ymax=1,
xmin=-3.141,xmax=3.141,
ticklabel shift=0.5cm, % shift all tick labels 0.5cm outwards
%
axis y line*=left, % only one y axis on the left, * switches off the arrow tip
y axis line style={xshift=-0.5cm}, % shift y axis 0.5 cm to the left
ytick style={xshift=-0.5cm}, % shift y axis tick marks 0.5 cm to the left
%
axis x line*=bottom,
x axis line style={yshift=-0.5cm},
xtick style={yshift=-0.5cm},
]
\addplot +[domain={-pi:pi},no marks,smooth,thick] {sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]